# IdentityServer4 claims doesn't show any claims that I given to IDS server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm a new IdentityServer4. So I created the Identity server project and .net core 3 API. I have given claims to the Client. but  It's not showing in the IdentityServer MvC UI. even I not getting any errors also.

Here is my Identity server StartUp.cs

```
namespace Marvin.IDP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // uncomment, if you want to add an MVC-based UI
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

            // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // uncomment if you want to add MVC
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            // uncomment, if you want to add MVC
            
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and here the IDS4 config file

```
 public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            { 
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Address(),
                new IdentityResource(
                    "roles",
                    "Your role(s)",
                    new List<string>() { "role" })
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
            new ApiResource[] 
            {
                new ApiResource(
                    "imagegalleryapi", 
                    "Image Gallery API",
                    new List<string>() { "role" })
            };
        
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[] 
            { 
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "Image Gallery", 
                    ClientId = "imagegalleryclient",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "https://localhost:44389/signin-oidc"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "https://localhost:44389/signout-callback-oidc"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = 
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                        "roles",
                        "imagegalleryapi"
                    },
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    }
                } };        
    }
```

and here my API startup file

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                 .AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddTransient<BearerTokenHandler>();

            // create an HttpClient used for accessing the API
            services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44366/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
            }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();
            // create an HttpClient used for accessing the IDP
            services.AddHttpClient("IDPClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44318/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
            });


            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authorization/AccessDenied";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318/";
                options.ClientId = "imagegalleryclient";
                options.ResponseType = "code";               
                options.Scope.Add("address");
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.Scope.Add("imagegalleryapi");
                options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
                options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
                options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("s_hash");
                options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("auth_time");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
                    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
                };
            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
 
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for
                // production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Gallery}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

here I add MyTestUser

```
  public class TestUsers
        {
            public static List<TestUser> Users = new List<TestUser>
            {
                 new TestUser
                 {
                     SubjectId = "d860efca-22d9-47fd-8249-791ba61b07c7",
                     Username = "Frank",
                     Password = "password",
    
                     Claims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                         new Claim("given_name", "Frank"),
                         new Claim("family_name", "Underwood"),
                         new Claim("address", "Main Road 1"),
                         new Claim("role", "FreeUser")
                     }
                 },
                 new TestUser
                 {
                     SubjectId = "b7539694-97e7-4dfe-84da-b4256e1ff5c7",
                     Username = "Claire",
                     Password = "password",
    
                     Claims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                         new Claim("given_name", "Claire"),
                         new Claim("family_name", "Underwood"),
                         new Claim("address", "Big Street 2"),
                         new Claim("role", "PayingUser")
                     }
                 }
             };
    
        }
```

after logging to Identity user there MVC UI showing this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImtA0.png

Comment: Have you set the Role claim in the user details? Perhaps add the user definition to the Question. Also I would also check in Fiddler, and look for the request to the /UserInfo endpoint to see what claims about the user do you actually get back. Also, have you made sure that you consented to the scopes?

Comment: I added the User Class also\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you login using the **Authorization code flow** (options.ResponseType = "code";) then that means that there must be a user involved, and the **roles** is a IdentityResource scope, meaning that it will only be included when the user with the claim **role** is added to IdentityServer.

Do add a User to IdentityServer to get it to work.

Comment: I didn't get what is this and where to add "options.ResponseType = "code""

Comment: You already have that in your API client and that is fine, but if you use code, you need to have a user.

Comment: Did you give consent to the requested scopes when you logged in?

Comment: Yes given scope to Client. And User is there in my inMemorydatabase

Comment: Try to add options.Prompt = "consent"; in your client, to force the consent screen to be shown.  Do logout and then login again.does that help?

Comment: Are you happy with my answer or are there something missing? If not, please mark my answer as accepted :-)